# how can I iterate specific rows of excel worksheet if I have row numbers using openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am new to programming, currently learning python and openpyxl for excel file manipulations.
I am writing a script to help in updating repairs database which picks specific records in an excel sheet.
I have written a script where I can get the row numbers of the excel data I need to update but the challenge now is about how to create a list within a list of a row (record) through iteration.

For example I have found that I need data from rows 22, 23, 34 & 35. Is there a way of getting the data of these rows without having to change min_row and max_row number for every instance of row?

the portion of the code that I need rewritten is:

```
# copy the record on the rows of the row numbers found above.
rows_records = []
row_record = []
for row_cells in ws2.iter_rows(min_row=23, max_row=23, min_col=1, max_col = 6):
    for cell in row_cells:
        row_record.append(cell.value)
        rows_records.append(row_record)
print(row_record)
print(rows_records)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXkiz.png)

Comment: Hi I don't know if this is helpful but [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/index.html) is a very useful Python package for these operations. You can also read Excel spreadsheets, cf [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

Comment: Hi Patrick. I will try to learn pandas after this. I quess I was just scared to start learning it because i felt it is complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since openpyxl return a generator you have to convert it to a list to access an index in particular

```py
    import openpyxl

    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('numbers.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook .active
    rows = list(worksheet.iter_rows(max_col=6, values_only=True))
    values = []
    row_indices = [21, 22, 23, 34, 35]
    for row_index in row_indices:
        values.append(rows[row_index])
```

Comment: Thanks MSR974!  It worked as I desired but picks extra columns beyond column 6. Is there a way I can limit it to max_column = 6?

Comment: No problem ! ^^
you can add your max_column in the iter_rows function like you did previously in your example.
I'll edit my answer to add it

Answer (score 1):

Technically the same as accepted answer

```
sheet : Sheet = book.active

indices : set[int] = {10, 20, }
rows : Iterable[int] = (row for i, row in enumerate(sheet.rows, 1) if i in indices)

for row in rows:
    ... do whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import openpyxl


book = openpyxl.load_workbook('numbers.xlsx')

sheet = book.active

rows = sheet.rows

values = []
your_row_indices = [21,22,23]
for row in rows[your_row_indices]:
    for cell in row:
        values.append(cell.value)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot abdulsaboor for your quick response. When I make the change using your script above it gives me this error message: " for row in rows[your_row_indices]:       
TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable." Is there a way of removing the error. I am reading about the error